# How to set gender and age of a facebook test user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating test users in facebook for testing my app and there is a need for me to set the gender and age of the newly created test user. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible with [Test Users api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/) yet but you can simply log in as any test user and change whatever information you need manually - like you do with your own Facebook account.

**Edit**
You can use such tools as PhantomJs or Selenium - just code a script to log on and change user's data. And call it when adding new test user.

Comment: Pity, because I was looking for a way via the test users api or the graph api for complete automation, but I'll use this. Thanks!